# Unable to import NFT in the Temple wallet as collectible

Tags: smartpy, nft, tokens, temple

I am unable to import any nft as collectible in my temple wallet. Instead it is being imported as a token. I want it to show up in my wallet with the picture as a collectible.

The delpoyed contract is https://better-call.dev/ghostnet/KT1A7jooCViGCFcx3giy5gJPniViVRcx58Qr

The smartpy code i have used for the nft contract is -

```
import smartpy as sp

FA2 = sp.io.import_script_from_url("https://smartpy.io/templates/fa2_lib.py")

class TezDevNft(FA2.Fa2Nft):
    @sp.entry_point
    def mint(self, owner, token_info):
        token_id = self.data.last_token_id
        self.data.ledger[token_id] = owner
        self.data.token_metadata[token_id] = sp.record(token_id = token_id, token_info = token_info)
        self.data.last_token_id += 1


@sp.add_test(name="Test tezDevNft")
def test():
    sc = sp.test_scenario()
    tezDevNft = TezDevNft(
    metadata = sp.utils.metadata_of_url(
    "ipfs://QmRqg5DwUXmYmRRsZhBjoduaAdDgTc3baoxMTA3a3V35hT"))

    sc += tezDevNft

    alice = sp.address("tz1cKCuTgMvP7KKGJ8c2uBcFFBcGV99rN5Le")
    bob = sp.address("tz1Z3q4NGmcmsry2T4nPTHgZv9NVFuiGopzc")

    sc.show(sp.record(alice = alice,bob = bob))


    sc.h2("Mint")
    tezDevNft.mint(owner = alice,
        token_info=sp.map({
            "image": sp.utils.bytes_of_string(
                "ipfs://QmRqg5DwUXmYmRRsZhBjoduaAdDgTc3baoxMTA3a3V35hT"
            )
        })
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

Same problem here with my first contract. Did you found and fix the problem ? I think my metadata files are correct but cannot see any NFTs in the collectibles tab.

Here is the contract https://better-call.dev/limanet/KT1KM4589rV6SrR8hMm6pbmvXaeQ3iWTcXps

Thx guys

Comment: Your metadata is actually not correct. You can verify it on TZComet. Here is the link, paste your contract address to check: https://tzcomet.io/ If you do not know whats wrong, then better open a new question with your contract metadata

Comment: Thx @David ! Tzcomet.io is awesome to explore and check metadata. I made great progress with it. Not fully satisfied yet but I'm working on it.

Comment: Great to hear! If you encounter any issues feel free to post a new question with your problem

Answer (score 0):

Your metadata are not correct. For contract metadata see: [smartpy.io/docs/guides/FA/FA2/contract_metadata](https://smartpy.io/docs/guides/FA/FA2/contract_metadata) and [smartpy.io/docs/guides/metadata/contract_metadata](https://smartpy.io/docs/guides/metadata/contract_metadata) And for token metadata: [smartpy.io/docs/guides/FA/FA2/token_metadata](https://smartpy.io/docs/guides/FA/FA2/token_metadata).

You can verify it on TZComet. Here is the link, paste your contract address to check: [tzcomet.io](https://tzcomet.io).